# Schema Changes history using t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any DMV or query to track the ddl changes to objects on sql server 2008r2 that incudes the **LOGINNAME** and **SERVERNAME** of the **USER** who altered the specific object

I'm trying to create a monitoring tool that includes this feature.
Please help!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `DDL` trigger for your database like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ddl_log](
    [data] [XML] NULL,
    [systemuser] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [hostname] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [date] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [EventType] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [SPID] [SMALLINT] NULL,
    [SchemaName] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [ObjectName] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [ObjectType] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [CommandText] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [ddl_log_all]
ON DATABASE FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO ddl_log (data, systemuser, hostname, date, EventType, SPID, SchemaName, ObjectName, ObjectType, CommandText)
    SELECT 
        EVENTDATA(), SYSTEM_USER, HOST_NAME(), GETDATE(), 
        EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]','smallint'),
        EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [ddl_log_all] ON DATABASE
GO
```

Then any change will be logged in table `ddl_log`.